# Detect x-webkit-speech?

Tags: javascript, speech-to-text

I want to detect if the browser supports `x-webkit-speech` (speech to text in `<input>`s) using JavaScript, but it seems impossible. How can I achieve that?

(I want to display a message if the browser or its version does not support it.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can check whether the browser has a support for speech like this:

```
if( document.createElement('input').webkitSpeech==undefined )
{
  //no speech support
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! And a question more: why does it return `false` when it is actually supported? (If not supported it returns `undefined`)

Comment: @Derek, I think the webkit speech API is not a standard one also it does not support all the browsers.Currently it seems there is a support for google Chrome.So this implementation difference would be there as there is no  standard API.May be this is could be the reason.W3c has released a draft for SPEECH support last week.http://dvcs.w3.org/hg/speech-api/raw-file/tip/speechapi.html

Comment: So maybe in the future I can do `typeof(SpeechReco)` to see if it is supported? That would be cool.

Answer (score 2):

Detect on webkit browser (currently only Chrome) and maybe W3C in future ^_^

```
if ( !!("webkitSpeechRecognition" in window) || !!("speechRecognition" in window) )

       alert("yeah!")

}
```